# Why is pencil lead smelly?

Tags: carbon-allotropes, smell

I was writing down a chemical equation with my pencil and noticed its pungent smell. Could graphite itself be the reason for it?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help] for any unanswered questions about it.

Comment: Graphite itself doesn't have smell, diamond too

Comment: If diamonds had a pungent smell then they surely wouldn't be the fad for engagement rings.

Comment: Does graphite really smell bad? o.o

Comment: I'm wondering if the smell is actually chemicals used in the treatment of the wood in your pencil or even the paint as opposed to the graphite.

Comment: Don't you find the graphite in pencil has a distinctive smell? Even the "lead" refills for re-usable pencils have the smell.

Comment: Graphite has no smell at all. If you see graphite and at the same time feel some smell, it does not follow that the smell is that of graphite.

Comment: The "lead" in a pencil isn't pure graphite of course. It is graphite mixed with clay typically and who knows what else.

Comment: Graphite definitely has a pungent smell to it, but this is probably a result of it being loosely plated, dust easily escaping into the air. Diamond probably wouldn't have such a smell.

Comment: I agree with Max W , the graphite in pencils is not pure so it would be the impurities causing the smell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on false premise.

Comment: I've reworked this question. 4k views on a misleading, to put it mildly, question? Should be done long ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the carbon allotropes have a smell. If you smell something from a pencil lead (graphite), then it will be from the impurities in it.

Graphite is made from impure organic compounds that frequently contain sulphur. It is likely that you are smelling this. Mercaptans and other sulphur compounds can be very smelly. on its own

Comment: Just to add to the statement that none of carbon allotropes have a smell, this is because their molar mass is generally enormous, so they cannot form enough vapour to be detected by the nose.